# Is it possible to obtain the parse tree to a method in scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

Is there a way to obtain the parse tree to the code found within an object's method in scala?  As I understand it, this is possible to do for an expression that is passed as an argument to the reify method as shown below...

```
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    //I am able to retrieve a scala.reflect.api.Trees$Tree for this block of code...
    val i=1
    val tree1=reify{
        val b=i*3
        println("b was "+b)
    }.tree
    println("tree1->"+tree1)

    //Is it possible to obtain a tree for the block of code encapsulated in fooTest?
    object foo{
        def fooTest(i:Int)={
            val b=i*3
            println("b was "+b)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. Is your code indicating what you want? What you don't want? Does it compile? Also, `reify` returns an `Expr`—i.e., a representation of a Scala expression. It's not clear to me what it would mean to reify a method (static or not).

Comment: Using your suggestions, I've tried to phrase my question to more specifically indicate what I'm looking to do.  Thank you for the initial feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is whether you can lift a method defined in a Scala `object` (the closest thing there is to a "static method") to a function, the answer is yes:

```
object O {
  def oMethod(i: Int): String = i.toString
  val oFunction = oMethod _
}

scala> O.oMethod(23)
res0: String = 23

scala> O.oFunction(23)
res1: String = 23
```

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking to do, but realize that my initial question was very ambiguous, and have tried to rephrase it.